# Automate a Terminal Program?

Tags: python

I have a python script that before running it asks you for a couple of user typed options that need to be set. What I was wondering is is it possible to make a bash script that auto fills in the options as defined in the bash script for me?

Comment: I will work on it. I am on mobile right now, thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
echo -n 'First answer\nSecond answer\n' | python script.py
```

For more demanding tasks, use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I will try when I get home, thank you! Just on a long shot, anyone know of a batch version of that command?

Comment: That won't work as long the receivin script can't read from stdin. Commandline arguments and pipes are two different concepts. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504919/1107807 . But you could do a: `python script $(echo -n 'First answer\nSecond answer\n')`

Comment: There is a pure-python expect implementation: [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Comment: You can also use [Expect-Lite](http://expect-lite.sourceforge.net/) if this method fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is **Expect-lite** ([http://expect-lite.sourceforge.net](http://expect-lite.sourceforge.net/)).  It's a simple scripting language that will easily automate passing in responses to cli programs.  It's pretty light weight and will allow you to write a script that will run your python program.

For example, if you wanted to automate password login over ssh with it you'd write something like this:

```
>ssh root@host-021
<assword:
>>secret_password
# issue a command once logged in
>ls
>exit
```

However the output can be a bit messy.  Instead you can use the Python module **pexpect** (http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) which will let you write a simple python script to run the other python script while automatically responding to the prompts.

The same example from above would then become:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh root@host-021')
child.expect('assword:')
child.sendline('secret_password')
child.sendline('ls')
child.sendline('exit')
```

This in turn would mask the output, but you can set a logfile to log the output.  You can also set the logfile as STDOUT like so `child.logfile = sys.stdout`.

There is much more you can do with it which might be useful to you, and is shown in the documentation.