# Pass string to script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script, `download`, that takes a string and checks if a file has the filename of the string. If it doesn't, it then downloads it. All the filenames are in a file.

This command is not working:

```
cat filenames | ./download
```

Download source:

```
filename=$1
if [ ! -f $1 ];
then
        wget -q http://www.example.com/nature/life/${filename}.rdf
fi
```

Sample filename file:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

How do I pass the command output from the cat to the download script?

Comment: You want `./download filename1 filename2` etc.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pipe, standard input and command line arguments in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867/pipe-standard-input-and-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script `$1` is the positional arg on the command line. `./download somefile` would work, but `cat filename | ./download` streams the data into download, which you ignore.

You should read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), which will give you a good base for how bash scripting works. To fix this, change your command to:

```
cat filename | xargs -n 1 ./download
```

This will run `./download` for each filename in your list. However, the filenames may have spaces or other special characters in them, which would break your script. You should look into alternatives ways of doing this, to avoid these problems.

Specifically, use a [while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Handling_contents_of_files?highlight=%28file%29#How_can_I_read_a_file_line-by-line.3F) to read your file. This properly escapes your filenames on each line, if they were input into the file correctly. That way, you avoid the problems cat would have with filenames like: `fi/\nle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a filename to a file that contains file names to your script:

```
./download filenames
```

And then loop through file names from the file name in `$1`:

```
$!/bin/bash
# Do sanity check

fname=$1

for f in $(<$fname); do
   if [ ! -f "$f.rdf" ]; then
     wget -q http://www.example.com/nature/life/${f}.rdf
   fi
done
```