# Receive arguments via shell pipe in python?

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, glob

I have a python file that uses glob to find js files in a particular folder and then prints them:

```
print glob.glob(printfolder)
```

I want to receive the filenames found by this file, and pipe them in to another file that counts the lines of code of each of those files

so I'm using:

```
python findjava.py /home/alien/Desktop/ | python countfile.py -a
```

(findjava is the script that finds java files, that address is an argument to what directory it should search for those files, and countfile is the file that receives 1 filename and counts its line of codes, the argument -a is to show all (lines of code, comments, and other things it counts)

But I get the following output:

```
['/home/alien/Desktop/testfile.js']
usage: countfile.py [-h] [-t] [-b] [-s] [-c] [-a] units
countfile.py: error: too few arguments
```

so countfile is still waiting for the argument with the filename, which I'm trying to get with

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Any thoughts? ;_;

Comment: Consider [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

Comment: You are passing the result of `findjava` as stdin, not as command-line arguments.  If you want to use the output of one command as arguments to another, look at `xargs`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867/pipe-standard-input-and-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

Comment: Where is `countfile` accessing the command-line arguments? It's just reading `sys.stdin`.

Comment: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process a file')
parser.add_argument('-t', help='Display total line count', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-b', help='Display total blank line count', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-s', help='Display total source line count', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-c', help='Display total comment line count', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-a', help='Display all line counts', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('units', action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()

#print parser.parse_args()
file = args.units

Answer (score 1):

```
print " ".join(glob.glob(printfolder))
```

I think would work better :P

or maybe

```
print "\n".join(glob.glob(printfolder))
```

you are passing in a string like `['asdasd','dsasdad']`  ... which almost certainly is not what countfile is expecting