# Shell : Integer expression expected error

Tags: shell, unix, syntax-error

I am a beginner at programming in Unix enviroment and I am facing some difficulties at start. I am using PUTTY on Windows.
 Here is my script and the code but when I run it, it tells me that

> integer expression expected

```
#!/bin/bash

hour='date|cut-c12-13'

if [ $hour -ge 0 -a $hour -lt 12 ]; then
      echo "good morn"
elif [ $hour -lt 18 ]; then
     echo "good afternoon"
else 
     echo "good night"
fi
```

It seems that it doesn't work correctly with the pipeline or something; it doesn't translate the 'date' to the original date but takes it as a word, I think.

Comment: As a further aside, using `-a` as an "and" operator is explicitly marked obsolescent in the current version of the POSIX spec. Use `[ "$hour" -ge 0 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 12 ]` instead, if you want to be POSIX-compliant, or `(( hour >= 0 && hour < 12 ))` to leverage modern (much more readable) bash-specific syntax.

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html for the spec for POSIX test; the `OB` flag next to `-a` and `-o` marks them as obsolescent, and the `XSI` flag marks them as an extension to the baseline POSIX standard (so not all systems need to support them to begin with).

Comment: (oh -- and quoting matters; `[ $hour -ge 0 ]` and `[ "$hour" -ge 0 ]` are not the same thing: the latter allows for better error messages in many common cases, and prevents outright incorrect results in a rarer set of conditions. http://shellcheck.net/ will catch that variety of mistake for you).

Comment: Surely you would want `hour=$(date +'%H)'` rather than using `cut`... and it seems unlikely you could get a negative hour so the test for less than zero is a bit odd too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code shows regular quotes `'…'` and not back-ticks `` `…` ``.  Use

```
hour=$(date | cut -c12-13)
```

The spacing matters between `cut` and `-c12-13`.  In general, using `$(…)` is better than using back-ticks (see [Pipe standard input and command line arguments in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867) for a discussion of why).  Also, learn [How to debug a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script), which means `bash -x script.sh` here.

With the code as written, the value in `$hour` is the string `date|cut-c12-13` (not the output from the command) which is not an integer expression, hence the error message.  Also, you most likely don't have a command called `cut-c12-13`, which is why the spacing matters there.

---

As the comments to the question show, there are multiple other issues that should also be addressed, from generating the information you want directly from the `date` command to using double quotes around variable references, not using deprecated operators `-a` and `-o` with `[`, and there are those who'd argue that you should use `[[ … ]]` in preference to `[ … ]`, or the Bash-specific `(( … ))`, etc.

Comment: It might be worth explaining that `$()` is better than backticks because it can be easily nested and because quoting is easier to deal with.  And because people reading your code don't inadvertently think that you typed single-quotes. :)

Comment: @dannysauer: I've added an x-ref to a question where that issue is discussed.

Comment: thank you very much, understood. as far as bash -x script.sh i have made chmod +x so its ok i thing

Comment: @Georgez: Note that `bash -x script.sh` gives you a trace of what the script is doing as it is run; it is equivalent to running `set -x` as a statement within the script.  It is independent of the permissions on the script.