# What is the use of "< " in bash

Tags: bash

I can't differentiate between these two lines  of code as the output for each command is same

```
cat volcanoes.txt
```

```
cat < volcanoes.txt
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be read as a subset of [pipe, standard input and command-line arguments in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867/pipe-standard-input-and-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

Answer (score 4):

`<` reads a file (specified on the Right-Hand Side) and pipes it into the STDIN of the command on the Left-Hand Side.

`cat` takes input and outputs it to STDOUT.

If you provide an argument to `cat`, it takes input from there. Otherwise, it takes it from STDIN.

It isn't usually useful to use `<` in conjunction with `cat`.

Comment: It can be useful to control cat's stdin. `foo | cat prefix.txt -` emits `prefix.txt` followed by the output of `foo` -- a use case that's actually in line with `cat`s description and mission in life of *concatenating* multiple inputs. If you only have *one* argument to cat (which the "an argument" wording implies to be typical/usual), you typically don't have a good reason to use cat at all.

Answer (score 1):

`cat volcanoes.txt` passes *volcanoes.txt* as an argument, which `cat` will attempt to locate on disk and open.

`cat < volcanoes.txt` runs `cat` with no arguments, and the ***interpreter*** opens *volcanoes.txt* as `cat`'s stdin.

For a clearer example, try testing with multiple files:

```
echo 1 > a
echo 2 > b
```

now you can see the difference by comparing

```
grep . a b
```

vs

```
cat a b | grep .
```

In the first one, `a` & `b` are passed as arguments, so `grep` opens them itself and knows the source of each line of data, so it tells you which file each line came from.

```
$: grep . a b
a:1
b:2
```

Done the second way, `cat` reads both files and puts the content on `grep`'s stdin as a single anonymized stream, much the same as you did with a single file when you said `cat < volcanoes.txt`. This way, `grep` only knows data is coming on stdin, and it can't give you the additional info.

```
$: cat a b | grep .
1
2
```

For `cat`, it's functionally the same because of what `cat` is and does, but it's still mechanically different, and for some programs the difference could be crippling, or at least relevant.